# longtable name doesn't appear

Tags: captions, longtable, subcaption

The name doesn't appear.
this is the code.

```
\begin{longtable}[c]{p{3.8cm}p{3.6cm}p{4.1cm}p{5.1cm}}
\captionof{table}{\textbf{Summary of key ECD interventions in Cuba.}}
\toprule \textbf{Dominant ECD Sector} & \textbf{Intervention / Institution} &   \textbf{Target of population} & \textbf{Availability} \\ \midrule
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c} {{\tablename\ \thetable{. Summary of key ECD interventions in Cuba.} -- Continue 
        from previous page}} \\
\toprule \textbf{Dominant ECD Sector} & \textbf{Intervention / Institution} &   \textbf{Target of population} & \textbf{Availability} \\ \midrule
\endhead
\multicolumn{4}{r}{To be continued  next page...} \\ \midrule
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
\multirow{7}{*}{\textbf{Education}}
& Day Care Centres
(círculos infantiles) & Children aged 1-6 whose mother works &  1078 day care centres in the country \\ 
& Preschool Grade &     All children aged 5-6 & In primary schools or day care centres\\
& Educate Your Child Programme &    Children aged 0-6 with their families; pregnant women & 
In all communities \\ \cline{1-4}
& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{MATERNAL HEALTH CARE}}\\
& Prevention of preconception risks & All women & In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Prenatal care & All pregnant women &
In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office, in polyclinics and hospitals for
specialised controls \\
& Maternity homes & Pregnant women with risks that do not require hospitalization &
138 maternity homes in the
country\\ 
\multirow{10}{*}{\textbf{Health/Nutrition}}\\
\cline{2-4}
& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{CHILD HEALTH CARE}}\\
& Institutionalised birth & All children & In hospitals \\
& Care for new-borns with low birth weight & Children with low birth weight & In hospitals \\
& Immunisation & All children & In all communities: in polyclinics \\
& Prevention and control of diarrhoeal diseases and acute respiratory infections &
All children & In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Unintentional injury prevention & All children & In all communities: at the family
doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Genetic screening & All children & In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Well Child Care & All children aged 0 to 19 & In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
\cline{2-4}
& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{NUTRITION}}\\
& Breastfeeding promotion & All children, with special attention to the most vulnerable & In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office, and seven Human Milk Banks for infants in need located in provincial maternity
hospitals\\
& Prevention of anaemia and nutritional deficiencies & All children, with special attention to the most vulnerable & In all communities: monitoring at the family doctor-and-nurse office. Special interventions for children with anaemia or nutritional deficiencies (food and nutritional supplements)\\
& Prevention of obesity and overweight & 
All children, with special
attention to the most
vulnerable & 
In all communities: monitoring and
nutritional education at the family
doctor-and-nurse office \\
\cline{1-4} \\
\multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{Child
        Protection}}
& Birth registration & All children & In hospitals \\
& Care of children without parental care & Children under six without
parental care & In the extended family, or in mixed day care centres as a last resort (60
children under six in this situation) \\
& Care of children with disabilities & Children under six with disabilities & In all communities: included in
education institutions (regular or specialised), monitored by the family doctor and the municipal
Centre for Diagnosis and Orientation \\
& Protection against violence, abuse and neglect & Children in difficult living situations; child victims of
violence, abuse and neglect. & In all communities: inter-sectoral prevention system to address the cases of children in difficult situations. At the regional level, three Protection Centres for child victims.\\
\cline{1-4}
\end{longtable}
```

Answer (score 2):

Writing

```
\captionof{table}{\textbf{Summary of key ECD interventions in Cuba.}}
```

is a mistake. You should be writing

```
\caption{\textbf{Summary of key ECD interventions in Cuba.}}\\
```

Note the pair of backslash characters after the argument of `\caption`.

The macro `\captionof{<float type>}{<text of caption>}` should only be used if the object being captioned (a) shouldn't "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word) and (b) doesn't provide its own captioning mechanism. Since the `longtable` environment doesn't "float" but definitely does provide a `\caption` mechanism, using `\captionof` is not a good idea for a `longtable`.

The following screenshot shows just the first few rows of the 1.5 page `longtable`. Note that I've applied a few changes (beyond switching from `\captionof` to `\caption`) to the give the table a less-cramped "look". For instance, I've eliminated all `\cline` directives, I set a positive value for the parameter `\extrarowheight`, and I set up a version of the `p` column type that typesets its material in ragged-right rather than in fully-justified mode.

[image: n]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{longtable,booktabs,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength\extrarowheight{3pt} % keep this instruction local to the 'longtable'
\begin{longtable}{@{} P{2cm}P{3.6cm}P{4.1cm}P{4.5cm} @{}}
\caption{\textbf{Summary of key ECD interventions in Cuba.}}\\
\toprule 
\textbf{Dominant ECD Sector} & 
\textbf{Intervention\slash Institution} &   
\textbf{Target of population} & 
\textbf{Availability} \\ 
\midrule
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{c}{\tablename\ \thetable. Summary of key ECD interventions in Cuba. -- Continued from previous page} \\[1ex]
\toprule 
\textbf{Dominant ECD Sector} & 
\textbf{Intervention\slash Institution} &   
\textbf{Target of population} & 
\textbf{Availability} \\ 
\midrule
\endhead

\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\footnotesize Continued on next page.} \\ 
\endfoot

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textbf{EDUCATION}}\\
\addlinespace
& Day Care Centres (círculos infantiles) 
& Children aged 1-6 whose mother works 
& 1078 day care centres in the country \\ 
& Preschool Grade 
& All children aged 5--6 
& In primary schools or day care centres\\
& Educate Your Child Programme 
& Children aged 0--6 with their families; pregnant women 
& In all communities \\ 
\addlinespace

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textbf{HEALTH/NUTRITION}}\\
\addlinespace

& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Maternal health care}}\\
& Prevention of preconception risks 
& All women 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office\\
& Prenatal care 
& All pregnant women 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office, in polyclinics and hospitals for specialised controls \\
& Maternity homes 
& Pregnant women with risks that do not require hospitalization 
& 138 maternity homes in the country\\ 
\addlinespace

& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Child health care}}\\
& Institutionalised birth 
& All children 
& In hospitals \\
& Care for new-borns with low birth weight 
& Children with low birth weight 
& In hospitals \\
& Immunisation 
& All children 
& In all communities: in polyclinics \\
& Prevention and control of diarrhoeal diseases and acute respiratory infections 
& All children 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Unintentional injury prevention 
& All children 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Genetic screening 
& All children 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
& Well Child Care 
& All children aged 0 to 19 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
\addlinespace 

& \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Nutrition}}\\*
& Breastfeeding promotion 
& All children, with special attention to the most vulnerable 
& In all communities: at the family doctor-and-nurse office, and seven Human Milk Banks for infants in need located in provincial maternity hospitals\\
& Prevention of anaemia and nutritional deficiencies 
& All children, with special attention to the most vulnerable 
& In all communities: monitoring at the family doctor-and-nurse office. Special interventions for children with anaemia or nutritional deficiencies (food and nutritional supplements)\\
& Prevention of obesity and overweight 
& All children, with special attention to the most vulnerable 
& In all communities: monitoring and nutritional education at the family doctor-and-nurse office \\
\addlinespace 

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{\textbf{CHILD PROTECTION}}\\
\addlinespace
& Birth registration 
& All children 
& In hospitals \\
& Care of children without parental care 
& Children under six without parental care 
& In the extended family, or in mixed day care centres as a last resort (60 children under six in this situation) \\
& Care of children with disabilities 
& Children under six with disabilities 
& In all communities: included in education institutions (regular or specialised), monitored by the family doctor and the municipal Centre for Diagnosis and Orientation \\
& Protection against violence, abuse and neglect 
& Children in difficult living situations; child victims of
violence, abuse and neglect. 
& In all communities: inter-sectoral prevention system to address the cases of children in difficult situations. At the regional level, three Protection Centres for child victims.\\
\end{longtable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```